# Run an executable file using asp.net and show its return value

Tags: c#, c++, asp.net

I have created an .exe file in cpp which returns an integer . I have to shown this return value in a text box of asp.net .
My cpp code is here

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int addition (int a, int b)
{
     int r;
     r=a+b;
     return r;
}

int main ()
{
    int z;
    z = addition (5,3);
    //cout << "The result is " << z;
    return z;
 }
```

And the c# code for executing above cpp is ,

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   try
    {
        var path =Server.MapPath("~/cpp/sample1.exe");  
        ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo(path);  
        info.RedirectStandardOutput = true; 
        info.UseShellExecute = false; 
        p.Start(); // Send whatever was returned through the output to the   client.
        TextBox1.Text = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

When executing it, text box is not showing the return value . But when I put `cout << "The result is " << z;` in cpp file it is showing on text box. How can I display the return value on text box ?

Answer (score 0):

Use ExitCode property of Process class. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.exitcode(v=vs.110).aspx